# VHDL, Xilinx ISE, project navigator

Tags: insert, vhdl, xilinx, project-navigator

I'm new to vhdl programming and the xilinx ISE so pardon me for this noob question.

I accidentally triggered a hot key that triggered the insert function in the text editor. Its really irritating as I can't add new characters into the code without removing the next character.

Does anyone know how I toggle off the insert function in the ISE? Thank you!

Cheers

Comment: Hit the *insert* key on your keyboard once again?

Answer (score -1):

As Cthulhu already mentioned: Hit the *insert* key on your keyboard. This should do the trick.